# I would like to hear recommendation for a plugin to charge exams

Tags: plugins

Hello and a good day to all of you.

I need to ask a suggestion about a feature.

One of my clients is planning to charge exams.Which module/plugins would you like to recommend.

i.e Customers need to pay for exams.

Regards

Comment: Recommendations are off topic here, try the software recommendations stack instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used School Management System for Wordpress which you can find it on CodeCanyon. This premium plugin comes with handy features and one of them is paying for Courses or Exams.

Comment: i found pay-per-post useful, Thanks for your answer